# On hover get img src specified in a `data` attribute, then add an img + path to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have a javascript cursor, which does quite a few different things *(hence a few different blocks of similar looking code)*, where on hover it will add classes to the cursor divs so it can be manipulated be it a standard hover style, a unique class inherited for a `data` attribute or add text to the div, again inherited from a `data` value.

This all works ok on the included code. However what I want to do now is if an object has an image specified on it like this: `data-img="img/our-work/vbb.jpg"` - this image path can be added to an `img` element also within the cursor. Ideally there would not be an empty `img` tag when not active and this is only added along with the `src` path when required - however my example does have that hardcoded for now as that's where I'm stuck.

The goal is to display the image attached/following the cursor.

You can see this in the example by hovered over the "Image with Data IMG" text.

```js
/**
 * Two div's are on the page which are used to create a custom cursor effect.
 * `.cursor` follows the pointer whereas the `.cursor-trail` is an outer circle
 * that follows the cursor with a delay.
 * 
 * The original script was based on this CodePen example:
 * https://codepen.io/ntenebruso/pen/QWLzVjY
 *
 * But there were performance (lagging and jumping) issues cross-browser, mainly
 * in Safari (Mac OS). So it was re-written and this version performed better.
 * Previously `calc` was used for sizing and top/left values for positioning.
 * Using fixed values instead of `calc` (as we know the size of the cursor) and
 * `transform` wasn't as much of a performance hit. If we changed the size of
 *  the cursor in the CSS we'd need to update the values here accordingly.
 */

var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
var cursorTrail = document.querySelector(".cursor-trail");
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var timeout;

window.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x - 2}px, ${y - 2}px)`;
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                timeout = null;
                cursorTrail.style.transform = `translate(${x - 16}px, ${y - 16}px)`;
            }, 24);
        }
    },
    false
);

/**
 * Add/remove classes on click (anywhere).
 */

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    cursor.classList.add("cursor--click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    cursor.classList.remove("cursor--click");
});

/**
 * Add/remove set classes on hover.
 * 
 * 1. This used to start with `a.forEach((item) => {` but changed to `let` so
 *    that an additional (non-anchor) item could be targeted. `#hello` is for
 *    the image on the 404 page.
 */

// a.forEach((item) => {
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); /* [1] */
links.forEach((item) => { /* [1] */
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursorTrail.classList.add("cursor-trail--hover");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursorTrail.classList.remove("cursor-trail--hover");
    });
});

/**
 * Add custom classes on hover if the cursor needs to be manipulated in a
 * unique way. If an element has a `data-interaction=""` value set. This will
 * be added as a class to the cursor on hover. For example, this is used to
 * style the prev/next arrows on the carousel.
 *
 * This could be set using a specific class but I've just left it targeting all
 * `a` elements for now. Which will add a class of `undefined` if no dataset is
 * specified.
 */

a.forEach((item) => {
    const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursor.classList.add(interaction);
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
    });
});

/**
 * Text Label
 */


let hasLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.projects__img');
var cursorText = document.querySelector('.cursor__label');

hasLabel.forEach((item) => {
    const label = item.dataset.label;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursorText.textContent = label;
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursorText.textContent = "";
    });
});

/**
 * Show Image
 */
 
let hasImg = document.querySelectorAll('.test-image');
var myImage = document.querySelector('.cursor__img');

hasImg.forEach((item) => {
    const label = item.dataset.img;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", label);
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "");
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Core `.cursor` (pointer) styling which is a small dot that follows the real
 * browser pointer position.
 *
 * 1. Add transitions for the `background-color`, `height`, `margin` and `width`
 *    of the element when the cursor is clicked and the class `.cursor--click`
 *    is added to it.
 * 2. Only add the `background-color` when the `body` is hovered over. Otherwise
 *    on page load the cursor is stuck in the top/left of the browser until you
 *    move it, which looks a bit crap. At least this is a bit more graceful.
 */
 
.cursor {
    color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor span {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        margin: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: background-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s, margin 0.12s, width 0.12s; /* [1] */
        position: fixed;
        width: 4px;
}

.cursor__label {
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
}

/**
 * A class of `.cursor--click` is added when the user clicks anywhere. When this
 * happens we shrink/make the cursor disappear.
 */

.cursor--click span {
    height: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
    width: 0;
}

/**
 * Core `.cursor-trail` styling which is a larger cricle that follows `.cursor`
 * around the screen but with a smooth delay/lag.
 *
 * 1. Add a lot transitions for various click/hover states which adjust the size
 *    and colour of the element. `transform` is the one for the smooth lag when
 *    moving the cursor.
 * 2. Only add the `background-color` when the `body` is hovered over. Otherwise
 *    on page load the cursor is stuck in the top/left of the browser until you
 *    move it, which looks a bit crap. At least this is a bit more graceful.
 */
 
.cursor-trail {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition: border-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s ease-out, margin 0.12s ease-out, opacity 0.12s ease-out, transform 0.24s cubic-bezier(0, .48, .64, 1), width 0.12s ease-out; /* [1] */
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <span></span>
  <div class="cursor__label"></div>
  <img src="" class="cursor__img">
</div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>

<div class="projects__item">
                    <figure class="projects__img" data-label="#1 Image Label">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18399245/pexels-photo-18399245/free-photo-of-brunette-woman-posing-on-a-field.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" loading="lazy" class="lazy-image">
                    </figure>
                    <p class="test-image" data-img="img/our-work/vbb.jpg">Image with Data IMG</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="projects__item">
                    <figure class="projects__img" data-label="#2 Image Label">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18427938/pexels-photo-18427938/free-photo-of-autumn-mountains.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" loading="lazy" class="lazy-image">
                    </figure>
                    <p>Image Without</p>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can add/remove the img tag depending on the existence of a data attribute. You can also keep it simple and keep the img tag hard coded and simply hide it via CSS if the src is empty.

```
.cursor__img[src='']{
  display:none;
}
```

```js
/**
 * Two div's are on the page which are used to create a custom cursor effect.
 * `.cursor` follows the pointer whereas the `.cursor-trail` is an outer circle
 * that follows the cursor with a delay.
 * 
 * The original script was based on this CodePen example:
 * https://codepen.io/ntenebruso/pen/QWLzVjY
 *
 * But there were performance (lagging and jumping) issues cross-browser, mainly
 * in Safari (Mac OS). So it was re-written and this version performed better.
 * Previously `calc` was used for sizing and top/left values for positioning.
 * Using fixed values instead of `calc` (as we know the size of the cursor) and
 * `transform` wasn't as much of a performance hit. If we changed the size of
 *  the cursor in the CSS we'd need to update the values here accordingly.
 */

var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
var cursorTrail = document.querySelector(".cursor-trail");
var a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var timeout;

window.addEventListener(
    "mousemove",
    function(e) {
        var x = e.clientX;
        var y = e.clientY;
        cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x - 2}px, ${y - 2}px)`;
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                timeout = null;
                cursorTrail.style.transform = `translate(${x - 16}px, ${y - 16}px)`;
            }, 24);
        }
    },
    false
);

/**
 * Add/remove classes on click (anywhere).
 */

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    cursor.classList.add("cursor--click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    cursor.classList.remove("cursor--click");
});

/**
 * Add/remove set classes on hover.
 * 
 * 1. This used to start with `a.forEach((item) => {` but changed to `let` so
 *    that an additional (non-anchor) item could be targeted. `#hello` is for
 *    the image on the 404 page.
 */

// a.forEach((item) => {
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a'); /* [1] */
links.forEach((item) => { /* [1] */
    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursorTrail.classList.add("cursor-trail--hover");
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursorTrail.classList.remove("cursor-trail--hover");
    });
});

/**
 * Add custom classes on hover if the cursor needs to be manipulated in a
 * unique way. If an element has a `data-interaction=""` value set. This will
 * be added as a class to the cursor on hover. For example, this is used to
 * style the prev/next arrows on the carousel.
 *
 * This could be set using a specific class but I've just left it targeting all
 * `a` elements for now. Which will add a class of `undefined` if no dataset is
 * specified.
 */

a.forEach((item) => {
    const interaction = item.dataset.interaction;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursor.classList.add(interaction);
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursor.classList.remove(interaction);
    });
});

/**
 * Text Label
 */


let hasLabel = document.querySelectorAll('.projects__img');
var cursorText = document.querySelector('.cursor__label');

hasLabel.forEach((item) => {
    const label = item.dataset.label;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        cursorText.textContent = label;
    });
    
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        cursorText.textContent = "";
    });
});

/*
 * Show Image
*/
 
let hasImg = document.querySelectorAll('.test-image');
var myImage = document.querySelector('.cursor__img');

hasImg.forEach((item) => {
    const label = item.dataset.img;

    item.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", label);
    });
    item.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        myImage.setAttribute("src", "");
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/**
 * Core `.cursor` (pointer) styling which is a small dot that follows the real
 * browser pointer position.
 *
 * 1. Add transitions for the `background-color`, `height`, `margin` and `width`
 *    of the element when the cursor is clicked and the class `.cursor--click`
 *    is added to it.
 * 2. Only add the `background-color` when the `body` is hovered over. Otherwise
 *    on page load the cursor is stuck in the top/left of the browser until you
 *    move it, which looks a bit crap. At least this is a bit more graceful.
 */
 
.cursor {
    color: white;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor span {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: 4px;
        margin: 0;
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: background-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s, margin 0.12s, width 0.12s; /* [1] */
        position: fixed;
        width: 4px;
}

.cursor__label {
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
    top: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 16px;
}

/**
 * A class of `.cursor--click` is added when the user clicks anywhere. When this
 * happens we shrink/make the cursor disappear.
 */

.cursor--click span {
    height: 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
    width: 0;
}

/**
 * Core `.cursor-trail` styling which is a larger cricle that follows `.cursor`
 * around the screen but with a smooth delay/lag.
 *
 * 1. Add a lot transitions for various click/hover states which adjust the size
 *    and colour of the element. `transform` is the one for the smooth lag when
 *    moving the cursor.
 * 2. Only add the `background-color` when the `body` is hovered over. Otherwise
 *    on page load the cursor is stuck in the top/left of the browser until you
 *    move it, which looks a bit crap. At least this is a bit more graceful.
 */
 
.cursor-trail {
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: fixed;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition: border-color 0.12s ease-out, height 0.12s ease-out, margin 0.12s ease-out, opacity 0.12s ease-out, transform 0.24s cubic-bezier(0, .48, .64, 1), width 0.12s ease-out; /* [1] */
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.cursor__img[src='']{
  display:none;
}

.cursor__img{
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cursor">
  <span></span>
  <div class="cursor__label"></div>
  <img src="" class="cursor__img">
</div>
<div class="cursor-trail"></div>

<div class="projects__item">
                    <figure class="projects__img" data-label="#1 Image Label">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18399245/pexels-photo-18399245/free-photo-of-brunette-woman-posing-on-a-field.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" loading="lazy" class="lazy-image">
                    </figure>
                    <p class="test-image" data-img="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Mouse-cursor-hand-pointer.svg/220px-Mouse-cursor-hand-pointer.svg.png">Image with Data IMG</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="projects__item">
                    <figure class="projects__img" data-label="#2 Image Label">
                        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/18427938/pexels-photo-18427938/free-photo-of-autumn-mountains.jpeg" alt="ALT TEXT" loading="lazy" class="lazy-image">
                    </figure>
                    <p>Image Without</p>
                </div>
```